# MySQLi ignores host parameter

Tags: php, mysqli

This is my setup (the IP numbers are fictional of course):

**Server A (10.0.0.1)**

hosts a database called `database1` with the user `db_user` and the password `db_pass`. This user has access to the database and remote connections from any host are permitted (I know it's a leak and I will fix it once it works)

*Update 1:* This server shows no signs of receiving the connection (like `connection refused` or something like that) Port 3306 is open

**Server B (20.0.20.0)**
hosts a PHP script which connects to the database with the following command:

```php
$connection = mysqli_connect("10.0.0.1","db_user","db_pass","database1",3306);
```

My log on Server B says:

```
Access denied for user 'db_user'@'20.0.20.0' (using password: YES) in <path-to-php-file> in line 42
```

The line number matches the statement, so it is indeed the statement above which fails.

Why? I explicitly specified the IP of Server A (also tried `server-a.com` instead of 10.0.0.1)

*Update 2:*
I ran the following query via commandline as MySQL-Root and this is the output:

```
mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'db_user';
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'db_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '<password hash>'
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `database1`.* TO 'db_user1'@'%'
```

Seems valid to me. What strikes me as odd is that in the log of B it shows it own address (B's address) instead of A's where the Database is located. My idea is it tries to connect to a database on server B where no MySQL user db_user exists.

*Update 3:*
I connected via SSH to server B and ran `mysql --host=10.0.0.1 -udb_user -p` and typed in the password => it worked. `SHOW GRANTS FOR current_user;` returned the same like on server A.

Comment: 20.0.20.0 is the IP of the client that tries to connect. You don't have permissions to connect, remote connection is disabled or your authentication details are not correct.

Comment: @Allkin please read my question completely. I stated, that on server A connections from ANY host are permitted. Username and password are copy-pasted so I don't expect any errors there.

Comment: Did you try without setting 3306, which seems to be default

Comment: @RST I removed the parameter 3306 from the connect statement, still getting this log message. I added something about the logs on server A.

Comment: Try this query on the server: `SELECT host FROM mysql.user WHERE user = 'db_user'`. What does it return?

Comment: The error message you got indicates that it connected to the server successfully, but the user was refused access because it doesn't have the appropriate `GRANT`s. Make sure you granted access to `db_user@%` or `db_user@20.0.20.0`.

Comment: @Barmar I ran your command as root user of mysql on the command line. It said % if I'm not completely wrong this means "any host"

Comment: Based on your updates, the only thing I can think of is that you're sending the wrong password in the PHP code. AFAIK, there's no difference between the way mysqli connects to the database and the `mysql` CLI tool. But just for completeness, what happens if you try PDO instead of mysqli?

Comment: I checked the password several times (also spaces at the beginning and ending) and copied into the CLI. I will try PDO, but it may take a while, I never worked with it before.

Comment: @Barmar What kind of sorcery is this?! It works with PDO. Please add all your statements as an answer, so I can mark it as accepted :)

Comment: Ugh, I really hate posting cargo-cultish answers like that.  I like my answers to explain what's wrong and how the answer fixes it. Otherwise, it's of little use to future users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't connect using `mysqli`, try using `PDO` instead. I'm not sure why, but apparently in this case PDO works.

Personally, I like PDO better than mysqli, because of named parameters instead of `?`, and the ability to provide an array of values when calling `PDOStatement::execute()`. You may find you like it as well.

Comment: I asked my hoster about this weird behavior of `mysqli`. Turned out, blocked mysqli is sold to be a "security feature". `PDO` works without problems. They probably messed with the mysqli library to send invalid credentials to the remote server but forgot about PDO.